# How to take 2 variables from one prompt box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a program that calculates the weight and the height of a person and then tells the user if he is tall or short and if he is fat or not
To do this I have the following code :

```
function Calculate(){

var weight = prompt("Enter your weight in kg");
var height = prompt("Enter your height in cm");
if (weight <=80 && height <= 170){
alert("You are slim and short");
}
else if(weight <=80 && height >= 170)
{
alert("You are tall and slim");
}
else {
alert("You have to lose some weight");

};
};
```

There is nothing wrong with the code but I am wondering If I can use only one prompt box to take those 2 vars(height,weight).
You may think it's stupid but I have seen it in Pascal.
For example:

```
 read(height,weight);
```

Is that possible in Javascript?
Also I would like to prevent the user from entering letters instead of numbers if that's possible.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to split a single string into two numbers?

Comment: Not as you have written it. The "prompt" function in javascript is not really used that much for serious applications, mostly just for learning and testing.

Comment: You can ask 2 thing one prompt, and ask them to enter weight <Space> height, then split values and get data.

Comment: Not exactly.I want to read 2 different vars from a single prompt box

Comment: no, it's not possible, unless you prompt for something like "Enter your height and weight as 'x,y'" and then split the value returned. And then what do you do if someone enters `500 pico-lightyears,12 stone`?

Comment: @ManosKounelakis: The `prompt` function returns a single string.  You can do whatever you want with that string.

Comment: @ArindamNayak can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, although it is not recommended - here without any input checking

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9u6bx3ey/)

`var weightheight=prompt("Enter your weight in kg , height in cm","60,170"),
     weight=weightheight.split(",")[0],
     height=weightheight.split(",")[1];`

Restricting prompt to numbers only is impossible. Instead show a [jQuery UI modal form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) and find any of the [hundreds of restrict numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+restrict+input+to+number) you can find here at SO